# Checksum Scheme

Tags: scheme

Ok, my friend and I have attempted this multiple times and refuse to go to a tutor because all they do is give us answers, and that doesn't help us learn anything.

As of now I can get the code to do one of 2 things, return the sum of the list or return the list itself, and we need to get it so it'll return the list and the last digit of the sum. Here are the 2 things that we have so far:

```
(define (add-checksum ls)
  (cond
    [(null? ls) 0]
    [else (+ (car ls) (add-checksum (cdr ls)))]))

(define (add-checksum-helper ls)
  (cond
    [(null? ls) 0]
    [else (cons (car ls) (add-checksum-helper (cdr ls)))]))
```

The first set of code does the adding and returns the sum. The second returns the list plus a `.0` where the last digit of the sum should go? Can anyone help us? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
(define (checksum ls)
  (append ls ((cdr (add-checksum ls)))))

(define (add-checksum ls)
  (cond
    [(null? ls) 0]
    [else (+ (car ls) (add-checksum (cdr ls)))]))
```

The return is:

```
(checksum '(4 5 6 7 8))
((4 5 6 7 8) . 30)
```

We need it to return the `(4 5 6 7 8 0)` instead of the `(.30)`. We have no idea how to just get the `0`. if we do `(cdr 30)` we get the list is not in a pair. Any suggestions now?

Comment: Given the list `(1 2 3)`, what do you want to return? The following pair: `(6 . (1 2 3))`?

Comment: We need it to return   (add-checksum '(4 6 7 5 6)) return (4 6 7 5 6 8) where the 8 is the second digit in 28

Comment: And you need a single function to do it?

Comment: Well we did two separate functions just to try things out, but trying to get it all into one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add-checksum` procedure is fine, but you can get the same result by using `apply` and the `+` procedure on the original list.

For the second part: is it necessary to store the checksum in the last position? it'd be a lot simpler to store it in the first position, by `cons`-ing the result of calling `add-checksum` with the original list.

Finally, if you need to extract the last digit of a number, try something like this with `n` a positive integer:

```
(remainder n 10)
```

For example:

```
(remainder 28 10)
> 8
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the easy way to do this is to use your two separate functions as helpers for the final function; one that computes the sum, one that puts that number at the end.

It may be that your assignment requires you to traverse the list only once, and to compute it on the way down---that's a somewhat bogus requirement, though, since the asymptotic complexity is the same in either case.

Comment: We'll we got what the layout should be on the return, the only problem is separating the sum. We need to have the cdr of the sum or just the last digit instead of the full sum. But whenever we trying doing (cdr 30) (as per example) we get 30 is not a pair.

Comment: Well I guess our question now is how do we split apart an element like if 28 is our sum it is one separate element. How do we ditch the 2 and just get the 8?